# Drupal writes on amazon s3 but not read

Tags: drupal, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Drupal based site running on Amazon web services. Uploaded files are stored in S3 bucket. When a user upload an image I can see it's saved in S3 bucket. But I can't see it on the page when it's called. 
What could be the problem here?

Kind regards...

Comment: What modules are you using? Are you using custom code, can you paste it? Please provide more info.

Comment: It gives 404 error for imagecahce files.

Comment: Ok, but can you answer my previous quedtion?